# Sum of squares applied in implicit function

Tags: linear-algebra

Mathematicians, enlighten me on my self-study venture. How does one transform the equation on the left to the one on the right?

$$5x^2 + 8xy + 5y^2  = 9\left(\frac{(x+y)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{(x-y)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 $$

The book I'm reading in linear algebra suggests sum of square procedure, but I'm not familiar with how that could work with implicit function such as the one above.

Comment: I edited your question. Please ensure that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: The 9 should be on the outside though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard example of transforming a quadratic form using a change of variables $x_o = Px$ to eliminate a cross product term.

First, let's write $Q(x,y) = 5x^2 + 8xy + 5y^2 = x^TAx$, where $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 4  \\
    4 & 5 
  \end{bmatrix}$.

This is a symmetric matrix, so it may be orthogonality diagonalized by finding an orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A = P^{-1}DP$. $P$ should provide the correct change of variables which I described above.

Comment: Right, but how do you factor the expression on the left such that you get on the one on the right?

Comment: That is the process which I am describing. You can find a suitable matrix $P$ which represents the change of variables by orthogonally diagonalizing the matrix.

Comment: When you are saying change of variables, I assume you are referring to 9 and 1 coefficients of the terms on the right. If that's the case, those came from D matrix.

Comment: No, a change of variables is a relation $x = Py$, where $P$ is a matrix which provides us the advantage of not having a cross product in the new quadratic form. EDIT: Above, I have used $x$ and $y$ as vectors, not to be confused with the $x,y$ which are the parameters of your function.